# Powershell format table is giving me issues

Tags: powershell

Here is my work, the time generated field is not coming up.

```
param ($redflags)
$count = 0
$n = get-eventlog $redflags -entrytype error, warning| where-object { $_.EntryType -eq 'Error' -or $_.EntryType -eq 'warning' } 
$f = $n | foreach {$count++} | format-table @{Label="TimeGenerated"; Expression={$_.Timegenerated}} -autosize
$n
Write-host "The number of redflags is $count"
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving? Consider adding more details to your question as it will help others to suggest answers.

Comment: You do not pipe anything to `Format-Table`, so it not show anything in return.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @PetSerAl, you are not piping anything to `Format-Table`. I would change the program to the following:

```
param ($redflags)
$count = 0
$n = get-eventlog $redflags -entrytype error, warning
$n | format-table @{Label="TimeGenerated"; Expression={$_.Timegenerated}} -autosize
$n | foreach { $count++ }
$n
Write-Host "The number of redflags is $count"
```

1. In your original $n, the Where-Object is extra. The `-EntryType` is already capturing all Error and Warning.
2. No need to use $f.